# all drupal 7 /user/*/* URLs produce blank pages. any possible solution?

Tags: php, .htaccess, drupal, drupal-7, wsod

For some reason, after the site was being attacked by a malware, all URLs starting with `/user/*`, including `/user` and `/user/*/edit`, would redirect to some advertisement page. now they are returning a blank page. I have tried enabling error reports display but nothing shows up on the screen — Just WSOD. I get `File does not exist: /var/www/user` though on the apache error log.

Maybe I can do a mod rewrite directly on .htaccess to target `/user/` URLs?

Comment: Something from the same subject: https://www.drupal.org/node/158043

Comment: Try "updating" the site. That is, download fresh drupal installation and replace your files with new one. Drupal can also work without .htaccess & SEO paths. And don't forget do set regular backups when you cure the site.

Comment: unfortunately the quiz module needed by the website breaks when we update the core and we have paying clients that use it almost everyday as their scores are needed by the school. we'll be rewriting our website codes soon, but while waiting for the "update" to happen, if I can fix the */user* WSOD based from the error log above, that would be great.

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas I have already tried enabling error reporting and "Change the shutdown handler" before posting this. I've also pasted the error found on the apache error log.

Comment: Also, generally speaking, WSOD is rarely really that. In most cases some errors should be printed, but they are disabled. Try enabling all error reporting in php.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

What is Drupal saying in the log?

You can enable the dblog module via drush and then print the logs:

drush @site pm-enable dblog

drush @site ws

*please replace "@site" with your value

Comment: if going to `/admin/reports/dblog` gets the same logs, i get no error or log whatsoever. i cleared all logs prior to visiting `/user/<user id>/edit` so im pretty sure no error is logged.